# html source of google search with php

Tags: php, google-search

I make simple php curl code to display html source of www.google.com.
here my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/search?q=".urlencode("test"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

but, why the html source result of my code is so different from original html source of google.com ? when i use my php code, in html source there is html tag like this:

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=
```

but, when I open it in the browser as usual like this : `http://www.google.com/search?q=test`,then see the html source, there no html tag like `<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=`
and many more the difference of the html source

Comment: Open google from Firefox 2 (just as you are sending in headers), source should be similar.

Comment: what kind of headers which I add to my code to produce similar source ?